# Deploying asp.net website using msi versus precompiled deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I read that pre comipiling a website using aspnet_compiler speeds up the website (by mitigating the delays due to worker process restart). But when you deploy using an msi, isn't the deployed stuff already in the pre compiled (MSIL) form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when you deploy your website using an MSI you first [publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it, which **precompiles it entirely**. Thus, saving some time on the first hit (regardeless of the value of `Compilation batch`).

This is how we actually deploy websites at work. Visual Studio's Web Setup project is very straightforward. You just add the precompiled website as content, set the virtual directory name and that's it! you get a next-next-next type of wizard as installation file

Answer (score 2):

When `Compilation batch` is True, eliminates the delay caused by the compilation required when you access a file for the first time. When this attribute is set to True, ASP.NET precompiles all the uncompiled files in a batch mode, which causes an even longer delay the first time the files are compiled. However, after this initial delay, the compilation delay is eliminated on subsequent access of the file.
The default is True.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx